# Error Number: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '5 DAY)))

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('`tbl_packing_list`.*,((SELECT SUM(`packing_list_quantity`) 
 FROM `tbl_event_packing_list` 
 WHERE `event_packing_item` = '.$data['id'].') - ( '
     .'SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`tbl_event_packing_list`.`packing_list_quantity`),0 ) 
      FROM `tbl_event_packing_list` 
      JOIN `tbl_events` ON `tbl_events`.`event_id`=`tbl_event_packing_list`.`event_id` 
      WHERE ' . $data['date'].' <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`event_end`, "%Y-%m-%d"),INTERVAL 5 DAY))) as avaliableQuantity');

   $this->db->get('tbl_packing_list')->row();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$this->db->select('( (SELECT SUM(`packing_list_quantity`) FROM `tbl_event_packing_list` WHERE `event_packing_item` = '.$data['id'].' ) - ( '
               .'SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`tbl_event_packing_list`.`packing_list_quantity`),0 ) FROM `tbl_event_packing_list` JOIN `tbl_events` ON `tbl_events`.`event_id`=`tbl_event_packing_list`.`event_id` WHERE '
               . $data['date'].' <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`event_end`, "%Y-%m-%d"),INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND `tbl_event_packing_list`.`event_packing_item` = '.$data['id'].' ) )   as availableQuantity',FALSE);
   $this->db->where('event_packing_item',$data['id']);
       $this->db->get('tbl_event_packing_list')->row();

Answer (score 0):

could be you have a )  more  in where clause  after 5 day try :

```
$data['date'].' <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`event_end`, "%Y-%m-%d"),INTERVAL 5 DAY)) as avaliableQuantity')
```

Comment: i removed alias name but still it showing error

Comment: is the same error or is changed ?

Comment: I have update the answer ..

Comment: after putting false in end of the query  its working

Comment: hai scaisEdge i posted my answer now its working